# Notepad++ "Replace by space" failure

Tags: tabs, notepad++, spaces

As I understand it in Notepad++ 6.5.3, checking `Replace by space` under `Settings > Preferences > Tab Settings > [Default]` causes the specified number of spaces to be entered into the document when the tab key is pressed. It doesn't. Instead, a tab character is inserted as revealed by `Show All Characters`. Is this an ID10T error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but uninstalling and reinstalling fixed this.

Comment: Further update: The reason a fresh install fixed this is that the QuickText plugin wasn't present. Apparently QuickText interferes with the 'Replace by space' setting.

Answer (score 1):

This setting is different for each language. In the Tab Settings menu, highlight the language that you're using and either change the option there, or make sure that "Use default value" is ticked so it uses the option you set under [default].

Comment: All the languages below [Default] have the `Use default value` checkbox checked.